# Regular expression to check if a string contains all specific symbols

Tags: c#, regex, string

the problem is that possible strings are:
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
(sorted)

and i have other one string that have chars to find like: adef

what is the regex to check if all of specified characters is in string?

test cases:
string: amnosxy
find chars: osy
result: true

strings: amnosxy
find chars: anz
result: false ( z not found ).

it looks like containsAll method

what is the regex to check? (it is possible to make it dinamically depends on find chars string).

I don't like solution like loop for each chars and check IndexOf..

Comment: all specified characters or all specified characers in the same order?

Comment: ordering doesn't matter ( strings will be sorted alphabetically always )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to use regex:

```
bool containsAll = !"osy".Except("amnosxy").Any();
```

Another efficient approach is using a `HashSet<char>` and it's [`IsSubsetOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358446%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
HashSet<char> chars = new HashSet<char>("osy");
bool containsAll = chars.IsSubsetOf("amnosxy");
```

Comment: @ПавелИванов: both approaches use a set under the hood which does not need to be sorted.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use regular expressions for this if it is guaranteed that both arrays are sorted. Just loop `input[x]` through until you find `toFind[y]` or until `toFind[y]` is bigger than input[x] -> which would mean there is no such element.

Edit: alternative RegEx: `.*o.*s.*y.*`, so just put `.*` between all those chars.